# Bring back sync status emblems on Dropbox folder

Tags: 16.04, nautilus, sync, dropbox

I recently changed the icon of my Dropbox folder to a custom one. Since I've done that, Dropbox no longer shows sync status emblems on the folder. Purging and installing Dropbox from scratch did not do the trick. I also made sure that I removed the folders *~/.dropbox* and *~/.dropbox-dist* before re-installing. Is there any possibility to make that work again?

**Edit:**

After having changed the Dropbox icon in Nautilus, it looks like that. The syc status emblem is gone.

[image]

OS: Ubuntu 16.04
File-Explorer: Nautilus

Comment: What are the contents of `~/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-17.4.33/images/hicolor/16x16/status`?

Comment: The dir contains six png files for showing the Dropbox status in my desktop bar. That works as expected. `~/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-17.4.33/images/hicolor/16‌​‌​x16/emblems` is where the emblem pngs reside, but they're not shown on top of the folder icon.